# template reference variable gives _r0 is not a function error

Tags: angular

I have a search field which triggers the search method when pressed enter.

```
 <mat-form-field class="search-field">
    <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
    <input type="text" (keyup.enter)="search($event)"  matInput #search>
    <mat-icon matSuffix>search</mat-icon>
  </mat-form-field>
```

when I press the search button I get the following error

```
ERROR TypeError: _r0 is not a function
    at UploadPhotoComponent_Template_input_keyup_enter_4_listener (upload-photo.component.html:4)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:14296)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:14331)
    at platform-browser.js:582
    at platform-browser.js:1278
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:27149)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:363)
    at Zone.runGuarded (zone-evergreen.js:133)
    at NgZone.runGuarded (core.js:27060)
```

However when I changed the template reference variable from #search to #searchFiled it works fine

```
  <mat-form-field class="search-field">
    <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
    <input type="text" (keyup.enter)="search($event)"  matInput #searchFiled>
    <mat-icon matSuffix>search</mat-icon>
  </mat-form-field>
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: The problem is probably that you define #search as reference while you already have a search function in that template scope..

Comment: This seems to be the case. Is there a particular rule saying the that template reference and the function name can't be same?

Comment: Not particularly, but it would make sense this should be problematic. You could reference search in the template.. which could mean either the search method in component scope OR the local reference. So you basically have a duplicate identifier in your scope. Just as this is not allowed (or possible) inside your component, it also shouldn’t be possible or allowed in your template scope (as this is also component scope).

Answer (score 3):

In my case,
I named my login function same as one of my local Template variables

```html
<form #login="ngForm">
            <input type="email" name="Email" #Email="ngModel" required email [(ngModel)]="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
                
            <br>
            <input type="password" name="Password" #Password="ngModel" required [(ngModel)]="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
            <br>
            <span *ngIf="showMsg">Login Failed !</span>
            <button type="button" (click)="login()" [disabled]="login.invalid">LOGIN</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your html. You probably have a tag like this:

```
<ng-template #searchFiled>
```

If you replace `#searchFiled` to #search you must change it into the `ng-template` too.